# How to implement restore if i uninstall and install the app again

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

I implemented in app purchase for Google Play. I have *DungeonsRedux* sample. here

```
restoreTransactions();
```

I know there is a method to restore transactions. But if i uninstall my app and reinstall it again "how do i know if i have already purchased an item?" I have implemented in-app purchase and restore for amazon but in amazon i got the amazon SDK which store the record of purchase transaction for test account. How do i achieve this in Google Play (restore capability)

is it necessary to create account on Google Play to get restore response?
if yes, so i tried to create an test account on Google Play.they ask for money.
If no,so is there any SDK to provide response. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to test it first with a sample app. Here is how you can test it.This will take care of your restoring problem once look at below sample app properly

**Step 1.** Install the sample app -[TrivialDrive](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html#GetSample)

**Step 2.** Now test with Static Responses: there are 4 buttons on Mainactivity replace the button item code with these reserved product IDs.

- android.test.purchased
- android.test.canceled
- android.test.refunded
- android.test.item_unavailable

For using these reserved product IDs you dont have to add items in your developers console application
Here is the [link](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-static) for testing your app

Once you have tested with above method, you are ready to test with your own product, Here is a detail turorial link to do that 
[Testing In-app Purchases Using Your Own Product IDs](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-real)

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert but I will try to help here. I believe to restore your purchased items you will need the SKUs of the purchased items. And to go for a test on that you will have to create actual SKUs for you app. You can do that by adding your signed apk to the Beta Testing and adding details to the store listings. After that you can add details about your purchasable items in In-App Products section. By doing that you assign Title, Description, Cost and SKU(Product id) for every purchasable item in your app. Now, to restore your items you need to have the SKUs of the purchased items and thats it.

You can do that by following steps:

1. Follow the following steps to get things done but you will need your signed apk to test the functionality (The same you will uploaded to the   Developer Console).
2. In IabHelper class create your own method, lets call it getPurchasesDetail().
   In this method use the following lines of code:

```
Bundle ownedItems=mService.getPurchases(3, mContext.getPackageName(), "inapp", null);
ArrayList<String> ownedSkus=new ArrayList<String>();
int response = ownedItems.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
if (response == 0) 
{
     ownedSkus = ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST");
}
```

Now, the above lines will give you the list of purchased SKUs in an arraylist, put a return type for your method and get it in your class where you need to restore the purchases.

1. In your class where you want to restore your purchases, do the following:

```
iabHelper=new IabHelper(this, "you public here");
iabHelper.startSetup(new OnIabSetupFinishedListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) 
    {
    if(result.isSuccess())
    {
        try 
        {
             ownedSkus=iabHelper.getPurchasesDetail();//get purchase list
             //Now you have the purchased SKU list in an arraylist, you can use SharedPreferences or something else for the further process.
        }
        catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
       }
      }
    });
```

4. Now, upload your signed apk with this code and the public key to the developer console (In Beta Testing phase)  and use the same apk to check for implementation done so far. But, do purchase items before restoring, don't forget to do that.

I hope this helps. Thanks.